# Vaadin 24: most simple Grid does not display in VerticalLayout

Tags: java, grid, vaadin

I'm new to vaadin and I currently explore vaadin 24. Why is this simple grid not displayed?

```
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    public MainView() {
        Grid<String> grid = new Grid<>();
        grid.setSizeFull();
        grid.addColumn(s->s);
        grid.setItems("foo");
        add(grid);
    }
```

This question was asked [long time ago](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid-flow/issues/313), but I could not find a working solution. In firefox and edge the grid is displayed as a horizontal line. I already tried `setSizeFull()` for the containing `VerticalLayout` (not shown in the code above) and to "wrap" the grid into a `Div`. What am I missing?

Comment: Since the logical attempt to tell the grid to use the whole screen did
not work, would you mind to share, where you are adding this view?  Do
you use a layout on your `Route`?  Or is this the "UI"?  Do you have any
additional CSS or theme running here?

Comment: I just checked again and found out that the solution from @simon-martinelli (setHeightFull()) works, thanks Simon. ```grid.setMinHeight(100, Unit.PIXELS)``` (without setHeightFull()) works, too. Simon's answer is accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, as you mentioned, that the VerticalLayout has no height.

This works for me:

```
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    public MainView () {
        setHeightFull();

        Grid<String> grid = new Grid<>();
        grid.setSizeFull();
        grid.addColumn(s -> s);
        grid.setItems("foo");
        add(grid);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, for my case the solution is to assign a minHeight to grid.

Comment: Adding ```setHeightFull()``` works, thanks.